# Page must be lower than or equal to 30 error in querymen nodejs API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Handling the pagination in server side using nodejs and mongo, passing the page and limit as query params like below:

```
api/list?page=1&limit=10
```

For page=1 and limit=10 it is working fine but not working for page=31 and limit=10 and getting the below error

```
{
   max:30
   message:"page must be lower than or equal to 30"
   name:"max"
   param:"page"
   valid:false
}
```

I can sense that this is due to default page is 30 and default limit also 100 but how to increase this? and also I may need to remove this constraint itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen/issues/26):

```
querymen.middleware({
  page: {
    max: 100
  },
  limit: {
   max: 100
  }
})
```

And if you want to remove this constraint use the below code:

```
querymen.middleware({
  page: {
    max: Infinity
  },
  limit: {
   max: Infinity
  }
})
```